# Determine value/column that caused constraint violation in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, name VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN TRY
declare @Source table (id int not null, name varchar(10))
insert @Source
    SELECT 11,'ABC' union all
    SELECT 12,'CDE' union all
    SELECT 13,'FGH' union all
    SELECT 11,'IJK'

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT * from @Source
SELECT * FROM @temp

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 @profile_name = 'Profile Name', 
 @recipients = 'email@email.com', 
 @body = Error_Message, 
 @subject = Error_Message ; 
END CATCH;
GO
```

This is my code working fine .. But what i want to include in the mail is ID which is causing the error as a reminder to some email id in This case it is "11".
How i can do this in some smart way ..?

Comment: Basically in a simple way i want the column name and data which is causing Primary Key violation in this case its 11 .. is there any method which can return the column and data in it which error message ?

Comment: Whar is your `@@version`? On  2008 (SP3) the error message includes the offending value. `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#0BC6C43__3213E83F0DAF0CB0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@temp'. The duplicate key value is (11).`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (Intel X86)   Apr 22 2011 11:57:00   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: I think i should go for Service Pack 2 .. but even if i got the desired result from it as u said ..whether i ll be able to have the result with the column name ?

Answer (score 3):

As Martin has commented, 2008 SP3 onwards shows the duplicate key value.
For earlier versions, you'll have to detect the possibly primary key violation and raise the error yourself, e.g. *for your specific example*

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, name VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN TRY
declare @Source table (id int not null, name varchar(10))
insert @Source
    SELECT 11,'ABC' union all
    SELECT 12,'CDE' union all
    SELECT 13,'FGH' union all
    SELECT 11,'IJK'

declare @duplicate_key nvarchar(1000);
SELECT TOP(1) @duplicate_key = ID
FROM @Source
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
if @duplicate_key is not null
begin
  set @duplicate_key = 
    'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. '+
    'Cannot insert duplicate key in object ''dbo.@temp''. '+
    'The duplicate key value is (' + right(@duplicate_key,10) + ')';
  RAISERROR(@duplicate_key,
            16,
            1);
end;

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT * from @Source

SELECT * FROM @temp

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 select Error_Message() ; 
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/handling-constraint-violations-and-errors-in-sql-server/ Very detailed article i found on google .. It fulfilled my requirement as i wanted with multiple errors presence but i m worried about the processing cost ..